# Change out shifters to be push-pull

Tags: shifter

I have a Specialized Rockhopper 29 that has a Shimano Tourney RD-TX800 8 speed rear derailleur and a Shimano Altus FD-M315 2 speed front. The shifters installed on that are Microshift TS39-8R which are push-push. I am trying to replace both with push-pull shifters. Any suggestions would be great!!

Comment: "Push-pull" could be reasonably interpreted to mean thumbshifters, where it's a simple lever without any ratcheting or return springs, or two-way release Shimano Rapidfire or similar shifters, or just any trigger shifter. Let us know what you mean.

Comment: I presently have a thumb shifters on the bike but they are push-push and I am trying to change that to push-pull.

Comment: Aside - you don't have to have matching left/right shifters other than aesthetics.

Comment: Shimano Rapidfire plus shifters push (the lower, A-lever) to move up the cassette to a larger cog while the other lever (upper, B-lever) is pulled to release the spring and shift to a smaller cog.  This same lever (B), in a shifter with "multi-release" can also be pushed to release the spring and shift to a smaller cog.

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming you mean any shifter with a downshift thumb button and a trigger type index finger upshift release, i.e. most Shimano shift pods.

The hoop you must jump through here is that there aren't tons that are 2x8 by design. Most are 3x. Running a 3x shifter on a 2x front crank can be made to work acceptably, and many bikes have been set up that way, but getting it dialed great so that "shift lock" situations are properly unattainable can be a little tricky. Given that you have the option, I think just getting a native 2x shifter is better. One option for this would be the SL-M315 set from Shimano. That's the only set I'm aware of that has the clicks you're looking for and is a matched set.